# fragments created programmatically inside frame layout and custom dialog box are not shown

Tags: android-intent, fragment, dialog

Please take a reference of following link:

[Back key on programmatically added Fragment leads to empty container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919433/back-key-on-programmatically-added-fragment-leads-to-empty-container?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have created one frame layout inside my main activity which contains two custom dialog box opened on click event of button and it works fine.

but after replacing fragment one after other in frame layout and again main activity is created using intent this two custom dialog box do not shown even though their on click event is called I have checked that using toast and log.